# Help I accidentally removed the Media Scanner

Tags: file-system, gallery, system-error, system-apps, media-scanner

A couple of hours ago I was cleaning out unnecessary apps on my phone (LG G3) using 3C Toolbox when I must have accidentally removed the app responsible for scanning my media. The Gallery & Music apps both claim that there's no media for them to retrieve yet when I use the file browser I can locate specific files on my phone. 3C toolbox won't allow me to create backups for some reason but that's another issue. I have the .zip for the exact ROM that I'm using but I'm unsure on how to extract the right app from it to reinstall. Any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

P.S. I have tried numerous media re-scanners on the Play store but none of them seem to work, I assume this is due to the media scanner itself being missing.

(Device: LG G3 D855) (ROM: Resurrection_Remix_LP_v5.3.8-20150309-d855)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you do since you have the ROM zip:

- Open the ROM zip in pc with winrar or similar.
- Inside zip go to `system/app` and copy `MediaScanner.apk` (or any similar name depicting it as MediaScanner) to desktop. If there is no MediaScanner.apk inside system/app, then check inside `system/priv-app` (it would definitely be in one of these folders).
- Connect your phone to PC. Copy MediaScanner.apk from desktop to its internal sdcard.
- Install and open [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en).
- - Enter the command `su` -- it will ask for granting root, grant it.
  - Enter the command `cp /sdcard/MediaScanner.apk /system/app/` -- this will copy `MediaScanner.apk` to the folder where it should be.
  - Now the final step, permissions. Enter this command to set permissions -- `chmod 755 /system/app/MediaScanner.apk`
- Reboot phone.

**NOTE:**

Make sure you copy `mediascanner.apk` to root of your internal memory and not in some folder. Else you will have to modify the commands I told above.

The name `MediaScanner.apk` might be different in your case. Just look around for an app that resembles the name. For e.g. in my phone the name is `MediaProvider`, so just look around for keyword `Media`.

#### Choice 2 in case you fail to find `MediaScanner.apk`, or any other problem

- From the zip file on computer you opened in winrar, copy the entire `app` and `priv-app` folders inside `system` folder to desktop. Then connect your phone and copy these two folders to root of internal memory (not in some folder).
- Install and open [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en), enter the following commands *one by one*.

  ```
  su
  cp /sdcard/app/ /system/app/
  cp /sdcard/priv-app/ /system/priv-app/
  chmod 755 /system/priv-app/
  chmod 755 /system/app/
  ```
- Reboot phone.

**NOTE:**

This may cause crashing of some stuff (only once this time, wont happen after you run all these commands and reboot). Dont fret, and think of it as normal.

You will have all those useless apps installed again, so you will have to remove them carefully again. This time, take a backup first and remove one by one keep checking for consequences of every app you uninstall by rebooting and testing.

Comment: I think the crashing in Choice 2 can be avoided if ADB is used and device booted into recovery. But yeah, those crashes are not a big deal. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your speedy response. When I open the ROM using Winrar and head to the system folder there isn't system/app folder?

Attached: http://i.imgur.com/ghDrSjc.png
                  http://i.imgur.com/7zdIg8w.png

Comment: That is corrupt download or incomplete zip. Its not even a rom. Do not install it and redownload the rom. Either that or there could be some other method. Can you send me a screenshot of root directory of this zip? Again, thats rom zip problem, not with my answer, it still applies ;)

Comment: This is where I downloaded the ROM: https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934543585

Screenshot:  http://i.imgur.com/b1F3bp9.png

Comment: Ok. The rom is fine, and my answer still applies ;) But thing is, the dev compressed it into a "lollipop update file". You can either follow the method here to extract this-> http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/how-to-conver-lollipop-dat-files-to-t2978952 (look on post #3 for how to do in windows). But in my opinion, thats way too much trouble for a mediascanner. So do this instead-> Go to recovery. Wipe system, dalvic cache and cache, and flash the rom and then gapps and reboot. You wont loose any data and all the default system apps will return. Its only easy way.

Comment: No problem, and good luck :)

Comment: Update: So I wiped system, dalvic cache and cache in TWRP & flashed the same ROM package & then gapps. It did the usual 'Android is upgrading etc' all the stock apps returned BUT the issue still remained. I've decided to wipe literally everything (after doing a thorough backup) and start afresh. Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: If you flashed rom, your media server is back. The issue is related to some other error (for ex probably media scanner not working properly or something). But media scanner has been installed, and should be working. Again, yes probably starting from scratch might help. But otherwise media scanner has definitely been installed. You welcome ;)